# F1 in Windows: Should it open the program's help screen OR show help text?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, desktop-application

I develop cross-platform desktop apps, and I recently discovered the joy of using help text on widgets. Then the user has a question mark button on the title bar and after he clicks that, he can click any widget in the window and see help text about it. Very nice.

Since I believe that all programs should be fully usable with the keyboard without touching the mouse, I found that on Windows, <kbd>F1</kbd> opens the help text for the widget that has the current focus. Pretty nice so far.

But... <kbd>F1</kbd> is almost always used for the application's help screen. So we have a clash. What should I do? Is there perhaps a different shortcut key for opening the help text balloons?

Comment: Personally, I HATE the help screen thing and I keep pressing F1 by mistake and getting a slow-loading annoying help screen. Help text sounds great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to page 233 of the [Microsoft User Experience Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c), F1 displays help, and Shift F1 displays context-sensitive help.